# How to extract input ID in rails to use it in javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, show-hide, dom-traversal

I'm trying to show text input field depending on checkbox checked value. Rails form helpers generate inputs with automaticly set ids. How can I refer to them in javascript.

Fragment of rails form

```
<%= f.check_box_without_bootstrap :standard_product%>
<%= f.label(:standard_product, "Standard product" %>
<%= f.text_field :product_comment%>
```

Javascript function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var checkbox = document.getElementById('????');
  var details_div = checkbox.nextSibling.nextSibling;
  checkbox.onchange = function() {
    if(this.checked) {
      details_div.style['display'] = 'block';
    } else {
      details_div.style['display'] = 'none';
    }
  };
</script>
```

Could you please suggest solution (that is not hard setting id for checkbox)?
Thanks :-)

---

Thank you very much. I just copied generated id from inspector...

I wish to know how to point to `id` generated by ruby helper `f.check_box` in `<script>` tag using `<%= ruby %>` :-)

Comment: Add the generated HTML.

Comment: Use a class instead of the id to attach your event lister.

Comment: inspect the page source (generated html). You'll see the id.

Answer (score 0):

Rails check_box helper is defined as:

```
check_box(object_name, method, options = {}, checked_value = "1", unchecked_value = "0") public
```

so in your code you can pass id in the options